# Regex to validate Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to make the changes in the given regex i.e.

`/(?!(.)\1+$)(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\2{2})(?!.*( |'|-|")\3{1})(?=.*\d{1})(?=.*[a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçАаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]{1})(?=(.*[a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçАаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ\d]){3}.*$)(?!.*[P|p]+(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*(FFICE|ffice)*\.*\s*[B|b]*\.*\s*[O|o|0]*\.*\s*[X|x].*)^[a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçАаБбВвГАаБбВвГгДдЕеЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ0-9 \*\"\(:,\/\.\\;&\)\[\]_\+#'-]{3,40}$/`

But was not able to as i was trying to implement:

- Three or more consecutive Standalone alphabets are not allowed.
- Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word. Example: `Haaadoop` is allowed but `Haaaadoop` is not allowed
- If more than 1 special character (In a word or Standalone) are consecutively entered, it is invalid. Example A-B is allowed, A- -B or A-&B is not allowed
- Consecutive  dashes, apostrophes are not allowed in any part of the string.

As the changes needs to be done in the above regex only. Please help me I am stuck in a middle.

Comment: Please check my edit. Is your regex that big? Is it a single pattern or are there two?

Comment: It is a single pattern.Yes it is that big.

Comment: post what you tried with correct regex format.

Comment: It is very unclear, but I guess the fix is: 1) remove `(?=.*\d)` (because `Haaadoop` would not match otherwise), 2) Replace `(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\2{2})` with `(?!.*([a-zA-Z])\2{3})`

Comment: Does that fix work? Try [here](https://regex101.com/r/0FDt4b/1).

Comment: Haaadoop is working fine but,Three or more consecutive Standalone alphabets are not allowed.is not working

Comment: Sorry, that requirement is very unclear. If `A-B` is to be matched, why require at least 3 letters in the string?

Comment: All alphabets cannot be the same in a standalone word. However, if they are a part of the word, we will allow the same. For example - AAA is not allowed  but Haaadoop is allowed

Comment: "word" or "string"? `AAA` will not be matched due to `(?!(.)\1+$)`. I think you should completely re-write the regex.

Comment: See we will allow Haaadoop in the whole string but if i enter only AAA then this wont be allowed.

Comment: Ok, try https://regex101.com/r/0FDt4b/4

Comment: how this will work for the regex that i have made.Second it should be alpha numeric.It Must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding special characters. Can the changes done by you can be made in my regex??

Comment: I do not have a slightest idea what you need. Please update the question with the *actual* requirements and valid/invalid examples.

Comment: 1. Minimum of 3 characters (includes alphabets and numbers, not including Special Characters)
2. Must have at least 3 compulsory alpha-numeric characters excluding special characters. 
3. All alphabets cannot be the same in a standalone word. However, if they are a part of the word, we will allow the same. For example - AAA is not allowed but Haaadoop is allowed.
4. Consecutive alphabets less than or equal to 3 are allowed in a word. Example – Haaadoop is allowed but Haaaadoop is not allowed.

Comment: 5. 3 or more consecutive Standalone alphabets are not allowed. Example - AA is allowed. AAA is not allowed. 
6. All numbers can be the same. Example – 111 is allowed. 
7. If more than 1 special character (In a word or Standalone) are consecutively entered, it is invalid. Example A-B is allowed, A- -B or A-&B is not allowed 
8. Consecutive dashes, apostrophes are not allowed in any part of the string
9. Allow special characters #&()_+[]:;',/.\\\-"*
All these requirements needs to be covered in the regex that i have mentioned in the question

Comment: Requireements are mentioned in the above 2 comment boxes

Comment: hi Wiktor,the below regex worked for me.Thanks for your help.Below regex worked for me.  ^(?!(.)\1+$)(?!.*([a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ])\2{3})(?!.*([ '"-])\3)(?![a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿ]*\W{2})(?=.*[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿè-ÿ])(?!.*[Pp]+(OST|ost)*\.*\s*[Oo0]*(FFICE|ffice)*\.*\s*[Bb]*\.*\s*[Oo0]*\.*\s*[Xx].*)[a-zA-ZÀ-ÖØ-ßŸà-çа-яА-ЯÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßŸàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿè-ÿ0-9\ *"(:,\/.\\;&)\[\]_+#'-]{3,400}$